# How do I manage adding the Registration id in Multicast messaging service at server side of GCM?

Tags: android, queue, double

I am started to exploring on GCM. Please clarify the following things.

By Registering with GCM server using the SenderID (Project ID get it from google API console), the Different device will giving unique registration id. I have used the following code to send message from server to all the devices by adding registration id as deviceid in the devicelist . I got the registration id of device by logging in the logcat.

```
        Sender sender = new Sender("MY_API_KEY");



            Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey("1")
                    .timeToLive(3)
                    .delayWhileIdle(true)
                    .addData("message",
                      "this text will be seen in notification bar!!")
                    .build();

       MulticastResult result; 

ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
             devicesList.add(deviceid1);

             devicesList.add(deviceid2);

            result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
```

Is it right way to send message like above mentioned?

If that's the case how can design the code it will work after release the particular application? how can i get the registration id of all the devices after releasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server needs to keep track of all the registration ids from the devices. Therefore, you need a database table to store those registration ids. Then you need to expose a web service, or a HTTP POST entry point for your clients to upload their registration ids.

After a device successfully register with Google GCM server, you will receive the registration id in the onRegistered() callback method in GCMBaseIntentService. This is where you want to upload the registration id to your server.